# Conditional required fields with checbox Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, field

i have this problem,
i have two type of customers:

1-private
2- school

I have some required different fields will display based on checkbox what the user checked (private or school).
I want create a conditional control when if checkbox school is checked, field school name is required else is not required.
I write this code but doesn't work.

HTML

```html
<input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="Private" name="select_cliente" id="select_cliente_Private" checked="checked">

<input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="School" name="select_cliente" id="select_cliente_School">
```

function.php

```html
function woo_add_conditional_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

  
  if (isset($_POST['Private'])){
    $fields['billing_indirizzo'] = array(
     'required'=>true
    );
    $fields['billing_cap'] = array(
     'required'=>true
    );
    $fields['billing_citta'] = array(
     'required'=>true
    );
    $fields['billing_stato'] = array(
     'required'=>true
    );
   
    $fields['billing_company'] = array(
     'required'=>false
    );
    $fields['billing_citta_scuola'] = array(
     'required'=>false
    );
    
  }
   if (isset($_POST['School'])){
    $fields['billing_company'] = array(
     'required'=>true
    );
    $fields['billing_citta_scuola'] = array(
     'required'=>true
    );
   
    $fields['billing_indirizzo'] = array(
     'required'=>false
    );
    $fields['billing_cap'] = array(
     'required'=>false
    );
    $fields['billing_citta'] = array(
     'required'=>false
    );
    $fields['billing_stato'] = array(
     'required'=>false
    );
    
    
   }

}
```

Comment: Where is your JS for it?

Comment: for hide and show i used this plugin: Advanced Checkout Fields

Comment: Where school name field is exactly? I see input school name radio but not text field  with name "school_name"

Comment: Don't know exactly how you're applying that function, but, if it's depending on $_POST variables, then they need to be submitted. You could probably then add/remove the "required" attribute or initiate alternative form validation via javascript based on checkbox being checked or not.